# Instantiate new object from Binding in xaml for Flyout

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

What I want to achieve may not be possible in XAML. If it is possible then its probably due to a XAML feature worth knowing. If not, then I've also learned something.

I have a button flyout which is data-bound to a view model. The view model provides a new instance of an object to the content of the flyout, via a `get` accessor.

Each time the button is pressed I want the flyout to present a new instance of the object.

[image: Object created from ViewModel presented in flyout, on button press]

**The problem:** The object is created only once, and re-presented each time the flyout is opened.

`ViewModel.cs`

```
    class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class ViewModel
{
    static int itemCount;

    public Item GetNewItem {
        get {
            itemCount++;
            Debug.WriteLine("Created item: " + itemCount);
            return new Item() { Id = itemCount, Name = "Item_" + itemCount} ;
        }
    }


}
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <Button Content="Create Item">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <Flyout>
                <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=GetNewItem}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Flyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Output:

The trace statement "Created item: Item_1" appears, but not "Created Item_2", etc..

The same data ("1" and "Item_1") is presented each time the button is pressed.

*Investigation*

1. I can make it work in the code-behind of the main page. I name the grid, and add an Opening event handler to the flyout

   ```
   private void Flyout_Opening(object sender, object e) {
       var gridDataContext = (ViewModel)this.grid.DataContext;
       this.stackPanel.DataContext = gridDataContext.GetNewItem;
   }
   ```

Works fine now! (but I want to do it in XAML)

2. I have tried implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the ViewModel, but this didn't work.

   class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       static int itemCount;

   ```
   public Item GetNewItem {
       get {
           itemCount++;
           Debug.WriteLine("Created item: " + itemCount);
           OnPropertyChanged("GetNewItem");
           return new Item() { Id = itemCount, Name = "Item_" + itemCount} ;
       }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
       var handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null) {
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I've given away 100 points in bonuses recently, so I'll hold off on this one. But, if I get a good answer, I'll consider it. Maybe even give it when my own points build up again.